# How to synchronize one function with others but not synchronize others between themselves?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have function a(), b(), c(). And I want to synchronize a() execution with b() and c() execution, but not to synchronize b() and c() (there can be only a() execution; b() and c() parallel execution, but there can't be a() and b() parallel execution or a() and c() parallel execution)
Can this problem be solved in Java?

Comment: You're looking for the `ReadWriteLock`, I'd say.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why not a simple lock?

Comment: @fge How would you achieve the asymmetry with a simple lock?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you explain how exactly should I use it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oops... I stand corrected

Comment: You lock for reading in your `b()` and `c()`, and lock for writing in `a()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as such:

```
private final ReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

void a() {
    rwlock.writeLock().lock();
    try { whatever(); } finally { rwlock.writeLock().unlock(); }
}

void b() {
    rwlock.readLock().lock();
    try { whatever(); } finally { rwlock.readLock().unlock(); }
}

void c() {
    // same as b()
}
```

Of course, this supposes that all three methods are in the same class, that there is one instance of this lock per class etc. If this is not the case, adapt the visibility/declarations/etc as required by your exact use case.